# Web worker not working with onclick

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

Im trying to work out the behaviour of Web Workers and I'm a little stumped as to why the output only shows and retains the message when the function is allocated to the window.onload event and also why adding an alert() to the end of the function momentarily shows the message before clicking 'ok' and the message dissapearing.

Appreciate any help, thanks.

```
<form>
    <button id="button" style="height:30px;">Say hello</button>
    <input id="output" style="width:200px"></input>
 </form>
 <script>
    var button = document.getElementById("button");
    button.onclick = function(){

      var worker = new Worker("worker.js");
      worker.postMessage("hello");

      worker.onmessage = function(event){
        var message = event.data;
        var output = document.getElementById("output");
        output.value = "Worker says " + message;
      }

      //alert("Message shows when this alert is here, but as "
      //       + "soon as you click ok...");

    }  
 </script>
```

worker.js

```
onmessage = function(){
  postMessage("Well hello to you too.");
}
```

Comment: Does the worker work if you add `type="button"` to the `<button>` element?

Comment: send the message after you subscribe; i'm guessing the guts of the worker are very fast at this point...

Comment: Yep, type=button has fixed it, why is this? Also dandavis are you suggesting I put the worker.postMessage after worker.onmessage or will this not make much difference? Thanks for the fix, any additional info on this behaviour will be much appreciated.

Comment: If you don’t plan on submitting that `<form>`, then keep using `type="button"`.

Answer (score 2):

Your worker sends the reply before you even set the on message callback. So when you do `worker.onmessage = ...` the `"Hello to you too"` message is already gone.

Always assign callbacks first, this also applies to `onload` callbacks on XHR requests and images. Do it like this:

```
  var worker = new Worker("worker.js");  

  worker.onmessage = function(event){
    var message = event.data;
    var output = document.getElementById("output");
    output.value += "Worker says " + message + "\n";
  }

  worker.postMessage("hello");
```

Also I am not sure why you're using form when it's a javascript program and you don't want to send anything to server... just use `<div>`:

```
<div>
    <button id="button" style="height:30px;">Say hello</button>
    <input id="output" style="width:200px"></input>
</div>
```

If you have `<button>` in `<form>` it sends the form and reloads the page when you click it - unless it's `<button type="button">`.